# How to render the map in phone gap using HTML5?

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to show the maps in mobile device using phone gap. 
Now i can show the map in System web browser. But it is not render in mobile device. I don't know how to render in the mobile device. Please let me know how to render the map in the mobile devices.

My sample code.

```
    <!doctype.html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width"/> 
<style>
styleone
{
position: relative;
top: 75px;
left: 211px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', 'Netherlands'],
        ['Amsterdam',0.9]

      ]);

      var options = {};
      options['region'] = 'NL';
      options['colors'] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors
      options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

      var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
      geomap.draw(data, options);
    };

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<table  width="100%" >
<tr><td>
<div id='map_canvas'></div>

</td></tr>

</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: wat? i'm a little confus

Comment: Can you show some (minimum) code that can reproduce the problem?